# Voting Corrected

Tags: support, reputation

Today morning I wokeup to see this, :(

[image]
I read the [learn more](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) part aside it. I don’t know why I got hit by this. It said,

> If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page.

Well, I found two weird upvotes on answers of mine which had negative votes. And those came up in the last 48hours or so. I ignored them. What should I do? I’m clueless.

---

**Note:** This morning it said -330. Now, it says -296. But I don’t seem to have had an increase from the time I was hit by this.

Comment: "I found two weird upvotes on answers of mine" How was there a gain of +300 from just two upvotes? What do you mean by that statement?

Comment: See [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857)

Comment: No, it was only +20, but I said weird because those answers were downvoted but they received an upvote. @GaurangTandon

Comment: @AvnishKabaj So, I have no other go but to re-earn them?

Comment: @MollyCooL Looks like it

Comment: I do find this interesting because your total adjustment is larger than 200—the daily cap for upvote reputation. But probably the system reversed two days at once or something.

Answer (score 9):

As a rule we do not comment on the specific details of such cases.

Suffice it to say that there were unnatural voting patterns - in this case *serial upvoting*, since you have lost reputation that came from upvotes. This is not proper: votes should be given for content, not the person writing them. As a result, the votes have been reversed. You may be able to infer that the reputation you have lost corresponds to the number of upvotes which have been reversed. In this case it is obviously quite substantial.

We can tell if voting patterns are suspicious, but we obviously cannot tell what the real-life reasons behind them are. If you have any idea how this could have happened, please take action to stop it.

Comment: I get that, but how are we supposed to know if someone has voted on many of my posts if I don’t know who has voted on mine?

Comment: If you don't have any idea, then so be it - just move on. Sometimes, though, there are clues - people you may have spoken to, etc.

Comment: Okay. Atleast if voting patterns aren’t alright, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @MollyCooL  That "voting corrected" message is basically to put you on a Sherlock Holmes mode ;) It's SE's way of saying: some user of this site repeatedly upvoted your content, so don your detective hat, and figure out who they were! :P

Comment: @GaurangTandon I’m no Sherlock Holmes. That’s exactly why I am asking for help :|. Even if I find, there is no way that I can stop anyone :(.

Comment: @Molly it sucks, but if only everyone knew upvoting someone instead of something is not doing a favor for them. If you feel you're getting upvotes at a much more rapid succession than you usually do, get ready to see them reversed. You'll never know who it was unless it's you upvoting yourself, which has a bigger punishment anyway.